# Adaptive storyboard (fit lots of buttons onto all devices correctly)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been trying to figure out how to get my app to look good on all apple devices. I will say I made this app very quickly and was not thinking about how it would look on different devices when I was making it. I was just having a good time making it. Until now, since it only looks good on the iPhone 6s, which is what I was testing it on the whole time. This is the basic layout of my app: [image]

Is there any way to format this without starting completely over or is it just too much of a mess to fix?

Thanks,
Austin

Comment: This question may be flagged for being too opinionated for the site. Also, 15 UIButtons is quite a bit for a 4 inch screen (iPhone SE). If you *really* can't find tie to refactor your UI - please try that first, as 44x44 is the smallest Apple recommends for buttons - consider moving things into a UICollectionView.

Comment: you should look into AutoLayout

Comment: As a very quick test - in the storyboard you could select the view controller and select "Reset to Selected Constraints" for "All Views in View Controller" and see if Xcode manages to add constraints that work for all device sizes. (It probably won't, and if it does, then it'll be for portrait not landscape) but it will only take 10 seconds to try.

Comment: Is this really the only View Controller in your app? Regardless, I think this app would be better as a `UICollectionView` with some type of flow layout.

Comment: I suggest stackview.

Answer (score 0):

Use Autolayout. That is what it's for. You don't have to start over; you just need to add proper constraints to all your elements so that they do the right sort of thing when the app launches on a larger or smaller screen.

Comment: When you add a constraint how do you know what numbers to put? And what are the numbers you put in referring to/relative to?

Comment: Whoa whoa. I'm not going to teach you autolayout in a comment!